# Drivers for a USB camera on Android

Tags: android, android-hardware

A company manufactures a USB camera (video & stills) that they want to pair up with an Android software interface. The camera requires custom drivers on Windows, and I expect it does on Android also. I know Android apps well, but not the low-level stuff around hardware, Linux and device drivers.

Am I right in thinking that if the manufacturer can provide a suitable driver, that the device would appear as a camera in the Android SDK APIs? i.e. if they provide a driver, I can work with the camera as if it was any other Android device camera? Does the driver need to be Android-specific, or if they have a Linux driver will that work? If the latter, are there any requirements re the specific Linux versions/distributions it needs to support?

Appreciate any advice or pointers to sources of information on supporting third-party USB cameras on Android devices.